# Where is the line drawn between material suitable for WebMasters or ServerFault?

Tags: discussion

I recently had my question closed on WebMasters where my issue was resolved stating that it was more appropriate for ServerFault.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19795/apache-2-2-21-upgrade-from-2-2-8-what-is-the-best-way-to-do-this-on-a-production

Does Apache administration not also fall into the realm of WebMaster as well?  I got a good answer that I wanted to accept and now I am unable to award points to the person who helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went ahead and migrated it to Server Fault:

https://serverfault.com/questions/312438/apache-2-2-21-upgrade-from-2-2-8-what-is-the-best-way-to-do-this-on-a-production

I agree that this question was more about the specific maintenance and updating of servers than it was about typical website operation. Per the [faq](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq):

> If your question generally covers the operation of websites..

Note that it says "operation of *websites*" not necessarily "operation of *servers*".

(Basically: webmaster vs. sysadmin.)

While there is certainly an acknowledged grey area there (yep, plenty of people are both webmasters and sysadmins..), this question was quite technical about server configuration, so I -- and at least two others -- felt it was a better fit on Server Fault with an audience of system administrators.

Anyway, the point of this migration and closing process is to put your question in front of the most skilled, most appropriate audience so that it can get the best possible answer!

Comment: I've seen some harsh sentiment toward beginner-level questions at ServerFault (and sometimes we see those questions migrated here) with the emphasis on "professionals" in the ServerFault FAQ - [case in point](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1760/server-fault-is-for-system-administrators-in-a-professional-capacity). Are install questions no longer considered within the realm of "doing homework" as you put it? (Definitely don't want to see a question migrated only to be downvoted/closed at SF)

Comment: I see it as more about *quality* of content than "is this person an expert?" in this case it was a very well-written question that was clear, complete, and showed effort and research.

Comment: @Jeff, Thank you for the succinct explanation and giving me the chance to award an answer.